# SQL Statement for displaying sum column in resulted query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables - the first table describes the project works and sub-works as the next :

| PROJECT_ID | WORK_ID | MAIN_WORK_ID | WORK_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 1 | Building-01 |
| 1 | 11 | 1 | Building-01 |

The second table describes the work activities:

| ACTIVITY_ID | PROJECT_ID | WORK_ID | ACTIVITY_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 | Tiling |
| 2 | 1 | 10 | Metal Works |
| 3 | 1 | 11 | Wood Works |

And the third table includes the activities cost:

| ACTIVITY_ID | PROJECT_ID | ACTIVITY_COST |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 500 |
| 1 | 1 | 750 |
| 2 | 1 | 350 |
| 3 | 1 | 150 |

I have created this query to order the first table by work & sub-works arrangement:

```
SELECT 
    a.WORK_ID, a.MAIN_WORK_ID, a.WORK_NAME
FROM 
    PROJECTSWORKS a  
WHERE 
    a.PROJECT_ID = 1
ORDER BY 
    CASE 
        WHEN a.WORK_ID = a.MAIN_WORK_ID THEN a.MAIN_WORK_ID
        WHEN a.WORK_ID < a.MAIN_WORK_ID THEN a.WORK_ID
        WHEN a.WORK_ID > a.MAIN_WORK_ID THEN a.MAIN_WORK_ID 
    END
```

Now I need the resulting table (From my query) to have addition column that contains the total cost for each sub-work, I know that I should use sub query or JOIN statements, but I don't know how to do it inside my query.

The query should return a result like this:

| WORK_ID | Total_Cost |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 1600 |
| 11 | 150 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the other two tables to take this result and then to sum(activity_cost) group by the others. Something like this:

```
    SELECT distinct
    a.WORK_ID, a.MAIN_WORK_ID, a.WORK_NAME,sum(c.activity_cost) total_cost
FROM 
    PROJECTSWORKS a  join activities b on a.project_id=b.project_id 
  and a.work_id=b.work_id
  join activities_cost c on c.activity_id=b.activity_id
WHERE 
    a.PROJEcT_ID = 1
  group by a.WORK_ID, a.MAIN_WORK_ID, a.WORK_NAME
```

here is an example [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/UZoqMEoz)